# Resizing HFS+ volume after cloning

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I cloned a disk containing an HFS+ volume to a larger disk using the command line `dd` utility.  Now I want to grow the HFS+ volume to fill the new disk.  There's an EFI partition before the HFS+ volume in the partition table but nothing after it.

When I attempt to resize the HFS+ volume in Disk Utility, it acts like everything works, but completes in about 4 seconds without making any changes to the partition table.  Trying from the command line using `sudo diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk3s2 0` gives `0 does not appear to be a valid disk size`.  If I use a size of `2T` instead, I get the error `Error: -5341: MediaKit reports partition (map) too small`.

How can I resize this partition?  I'd prefer not to have to copy the data to the new drive all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following instructions from [this helpful article](http://blog.kyodium.net/2010/11/increase-disk-and-partition-size-in.html), I wiped and rebuilt the partition table (GPT).  Basic commands used:

```
sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk3
sudo gpt show /dev/disk3 > ~/tmp/disk3-gpt
sudo gpt destroy /dev/disk3
sudo gpt create -f /dev/disk3    # -f for MBR compatibility
sudo gpt add -b ${start} -s ${size} -t ${type_guid} /dev/disk3
# repeat above command for each partition to be re-added
```

Afterwards, I used the `Disk Utility` application to resize the HFS+ volume.  It worked!

OSX may remount partitions immediately after they are re-added; in this case, you will need to unmount them again before continuing to re-add more partitions.

If the command line is not your thing, well, then you probably didn't clone your drive with `dd` in the first place.

Comment: Worked for me. I rebuilt the GPT table and now I can resize the main hfs partition. You have to use the `gpt destroy` command instead of `gpt delete` though ([ref](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/gpt.8.html)).

Comment: Destroying the GPT just to relocate the backup table is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

This is really terrifying that the only answer suggest to overwrite your gpt table.

The correct and safest solution, with explanation, is from [this comment](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2010/11/19/migrate-os-x-to-a-bigger-hard-disk/#comment-8567).

1. download GParted-Live CD from http://www.gparted.org/download.php
2. boot from this CD
3. accept the suggestion to enable the full disk
4. reboot from mac OSX
5. try again – now you can resize it!

Explanation:

The only problem is the disk header which exists twice: at the beginning and at the end of of the disk. Somehow Mac OSX shows the real disk size, but is not capable to change the GPT size header and to relocate the second “header” to the real disk end.

Comment: this doesnt work - gparted sees my main hfs partition as "unknown"

Comment: The terminal utility `gdisk` offers an operation called "relocate backup data structures to end of disk" through its expert options, which does exactly that without a cryptic message, and it can run on macOS or the macOS recovery environment.

Answer (score 0):

I add another answer, because

- I think there is a safer way repairing the GPT than @intuited did
- it works from standard Linux except actual resizing
- it cares for SSD trim as far as it's possible with HFS+.

So, you need to do this only if you want to make sure most of the actually empty blocks are marked as empty on your SSD for performance (and wear?) reasons.

If you are not working with an SSD you may skip most of this and only do step 2 for the whole disk (just omit `count=220`), then step 3 and finally 7.

Now let's start. My source is SDI, target SDH. Be sure to double check this for every command, as mistakes may be fatal.

1. secure erase the target SSD, as described here https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/SSD_Secure_Erase because HFS+ cannot trim the SSD.
2. clone partition table and EFI partition using (let's say 10% more than the size of your EFI partition)

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/sdi of=/dev/sdh bs=1M count=220
   ```
3. repair the GPT partition table using `gdisk` (in my case the source disk is larger because it's a temporary clone of the original. The original was smaller, though. So your error messages will be a little different)

   ```
   $ sudo gdisk /dev/sdh
   GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5
   ...
   Main header: OK
   Backup header: ERROR
   Main partition table: OK
   Backup partition table: ERROR

   Partition table scan:
     MBR: protective
     BSD: not present
     APM: not present
     GPT: damaged


   Command (? for help): ?
   ...
   x       extra functionality (experts only)

   Command (? for help): x

   Expert command (? for help): ?
   ...
   r       recovery and transformation options (experts only)

   Expert command (? for help): r

   Recovery/transformation command (? for help): ?
   b       use backup GPT header (rebuilding main)
   c       load backup partition table from disk (rebuilding main)
   d       use main GPT header (rebuilding backup)
   e       load main partition table from disk (rebuilding backup)
   ...

   Recovery/transformation command (? for help): d

   Recovery/transformation command (? for help): w
   Caution! Secondary header was placed beyond the disk's limits! Moving the
   header, but other problems may occur!

   Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING PARTITIONS!!

   Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
   OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdh.
   The operation has completed successfully.
   ```
4. check the partition table

   ```
   $ sudo gdisk /dev/sdh

   Partition table scan:
     MBR: protective
     BSD: not present
     APM: not present
     GPT: present

   Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
   ```
5. issue `sudo partprobe` so the system re-reads the partition table (I think GPT did already, but better be safe)
6. copy partition content using

   ```
   sudo partclone.hfsplus -b -s /dev/sdi2 -o /dev/sdh2 -L /tmp/partclone.log
   ```
7. resize using `Disk Utility` as described in the other answers.